# How to dump a function with import inside

Tags: python, pickle, dump, dill

I am trying to dump functions into a file, so that I can use this file/function elsewhere. I choose `dill` rather than `pickle`, because I need dependencies. However, `dill` doesn't work if the function has imports inside. For example:

```
def func():
    import numpy

import dill
dill.settings['recurse'] = True 
with open("test.pickle","wb") as f:
    dill.dump(func,f)
```

When I restart and load the function back, I get this error,

```
import dill 
func = dill.load(open("test.pickle"))
func()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input> in <module>()
      1 import dill
      2 func = dill.load(open("test.pickle"))
----> 3 func()

<ipython-input> in func()

ImportError: __import__ not found
```

This example works if I use `pickle` to dump, but `pickle` seems not to save dependencies recursively, so I can't save functions like `def fun1(): return fun2()`. 
Is there a way to dump functions with both import and dependencies? I feel `pickle` or `dill` only does half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  I believe `dill` should also work for you:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.10 (default, Dec 21 2019, 11:39:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> def func():
...   import numpy
... 
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> with open('XXX.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...   dill.dump(func, f)
... 
>>> 

$ python
Python 3.6.10 (default, Dec 21 2019, 11:39:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> func = dill.load(open('XXX.pkl', 'rb'))
>>> func()
>>>
```

The `recurse` settings means recursively trace references through the global dict, but don't store the entire global dict.  The default setting for `dill` is to store all of the global dict when pickling a function.  So, `recurse` can make the pickles smaller, but they can also fail due to missing references.